# Woocommerce how to use ternary operator to display featured products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have added the following code to display "Featured: yes/no":

```
<div class="event-package-content">
    Featured: <?php echo $product->get_event_listing_featured(); ?>
</div>
```

I would like to change it to display only the word "Featured" under the package if the package is featured instead of "yes/no".

Package screenshot:

[image: Package screenshot]

[Packages](https://www.motorhype.co.uk/post-an-event/) (shows after filling in details)

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your code:

```php
<div class="event-package-content">
    Featured: <?php echo $product->get_event_listing_featured(); ?>
</div>
```

With this:

```php
<div class="event-package-content">
  <?php echo ($product->get_event_listing_featured() == "yes") ? "Featured": ""; ?>
</div>
```